# Cannot get all possible overlapping regular expression matches

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string

```
Started: 11.11.2014 11:19:28.376<br/>Ended: 1.1.4<br/>1:9:8.378<br/>Request took: 0:0:0.2
```

I need to add zeros in case I encounter 1:1:8 it should be 01:01:08 same goes for date. I tried using

```
/((:|\.|\s)[0-9](:|\.))/g
```

but it did not give all possible overlapping matches. How to fix it?

```
var str = "Started: 11.11.2014 11:19:28.376<br/>Ended: 11.11.2014<br/>11:19:28.378<br/>Request took: 0:0:0.2";

var re = /((:|\.|\s)[0-9](:|\.))/g
while ((match = re.exec(str)) != null) {
    //alert("match found at " + match.index);
    str =  [str.slice(0,match.index), '0', str.slice(match.index+1,str.length)];


}
        alert(str);
```

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/qV3rI5/5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will probably do what you want:

```
str.replace(/\b\d\b/g, "0$&")
```

It searches for lone digits `\d`, and pad `0` in front.

The first word boundary `\b` checks that there is no `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` in front, and the second checks there is no `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`  behind the digit.

`$&` in the replacement string refers to the whole match.

---

If you want to pad `0` as long as the character before and after are not digits:

```
str.replace(/(^|\D)(\d)(?!\d)/g, "$10$2")
```

Comment: When I can look up documentation for `0$&` kind of expressions? Is it reg ex?

Comment: @RCola: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter It is syntax of the replacement string. Don't worry since it is not as crazy as regex's syntax.